# How to configure Azure Web Service to read .php web pages

Tags: php, node.js, azure, configuration, azure-functions

I am trying to set up a website on Azure, using the following tutorial.

https://www.wintellect.com/host-website-azure-functions-node-js-part-1/

It is all working well but I cannot seem to configure Azure correctly to read `index.php`, or any other php file with `content`.

Instead of opening the webpage, it downloads the php code.

In application settings I am on php version 5.6.

Any help here would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: This tutorial describes hosting functions written in NodeJS - PHP support is experimental and prone to errors. Why don't you use App Service instead?

Comment: The functions are in NodeJS, but it reads `index.html` page that I am trying to get to read a `index.php` page instead. What do you mean by App Service sorry? I believe my function app is in an App Service already

Comment: Function App is a Function App - it is designed to host functions, which are a simple pieces of code. App Service is a PaaS service designed to hosting full websites. Even if you(somehow, I don't know how) read PHP file from HTML file, the function is written in JS, thus I cannot handle PHP correctly. Please provide some code to make the discussion easier.

Comment: I am not sure what code would help. I have pretty much the same code as above (apart from `index.html` is now `.php`). Then in my `content` folder I have `index.php`. Though I have a function app in Nodejs, I am unsure why I can host a `index.html` without issue, but there is an issue when referencing a `.php`

Comment: Because `index.html` is a static file while `index.php` is a dynamic file. By using `index.php` in the way explained in the article, you will get PHP code, not a generated PHP page.